# Structuring React App for beginner

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not new to React philosophy, and have been reading and paying attention to the community for quite some time now, but would still consider myself a beginner when it comes to actually building something. Therefore, I have decided as a little hobby project I need to actually just start building something instead of reading countless articles on how it's done.

I have no clue what the actual application is going to do yet, but what I have built now is good enough to ask my pressing questions on how to structure it with best current practices in mind.

**Current app structure**

Right now, this is the current layout structure of my application.

[image]

As of right now, I downloaded a starter template that already had a webpack config written for me, so for now, I would ignore the assets folder within the "src" folder, since I am not even using it to serve my css and images. Those are being served from the dist folder, which I know is not the right way to do it, but hey I can only do so much at once.

**The Important Stuff**

What I need most help with from you guys is the actual structuring of my components. I have been reading that CSS Modules is a good way to go, so I was looking to do something like that.

**How The App Currently Works**

1. Index.js contains the routing information. I am using React Router.
2. App.js is the main component for the application.
3. As you can see, my navbar component sits alongside the App.js file, as I plan to add a footer component there as well. Those two components are global across the entire app, and will always be in the same place in the browser. (Not sure if that's good practice.)
4. Inside of App.js, I render the navbar component, and include {this.props.children} which just renders content from React Router.
5. From there, I basically have created two other folders within the components folder, titled "landing" & "login". Those folders contain a main component, and then render other child components within them. I was thinking that each folder should get its own css file.

As I continue to build out app features and components, is this a good format to follow? Logistically speaking, I have no clue how to configure the css files to be served for each of these modules yet, but was hoping my theory of how it works is correct.

**Wrap Up**

Just to make sure I am being crystal clear, say for example I decide I want to build a dashboard component now. From what I just explained, my thought process would be to create a subfolder within the main components folder titled "dashboard", create a parent component for it, and then create several other child components. Then I would plop a .css file in there as well.

Here is a link to the github repo so you can see exactly how it's layed out.

[Github Repo](https://github.com/DZuz14/quickapp)

[Working version of the app](https://quick-app.herokuapp.com/#/?_k=f6dumu)

Apologize for the lengthy question, but I wanted to ensure I covered all of my concerns properly. Any other suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: You might get into trouble soon when trying to integrate more features into your app, specially on how to store the data your app needs and how to handle changes on it. Check out Flux or Redux for that.

Comment: Yeah I've been reading up on redux, so I'm assuming Redux completely changes how I have this structured then?

Comment: Not at all! it just adds some folders, the idea is that components are kept independent for either Redux or Flux, so your (very good) react structure can stay clean. I recommend you keep on with React, and when you start doing things that just feel bad, like using a lot of global variables or adding innecesary things to your components, start thinking about going for one of those architectures.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips. They were quite helpful.

Comment: Yesterday I read an article on this topic and I think you may find it useful. https://hackernoon.com/my-journey-toward-a-maintainable-project-structure-for-react-redux-b05dfd999b5#.og1adzrph

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong answer or this one. You'll have to adapt to your project needs and notice what works best and what not.

In practice, some structures have proven to be quite useful:

1. Splitting by subject:
   This generally means to have a folder for each 'type' or subject in your app. For example: components, utils, media and so on.

The components folder could contain other folders to group components together with their .css files, tests and other complementary code.

This structure especially fits a state handling framework like [redux](http://redux.js.org/) where you would probably want a folder for actions and action creators, a folder for reducers, a folder for store configuration and creating and so on..

2. Splitting by app-part
   This means that you split your code in respect to logical parts of your app. Say you have a login form with a splash screen animation, all of those would be in a 'login' folder. If you have a user profile page with some dashboards then all of those and the components that they use will go into a 'user_profile' folder.

Do not torture yourself too much about are you doing this in the perfect way, because there is no perfect way. Just choose a reasonable structure the fits your project needs and go with it.

The important thing is to watch for the cases when your structure is breaking down. For example if you see that you are making changes in your application and you see that your current structure is making it difficult to refactor or to add features, or maybe it became too messy, then consider making changes to the way you structure your project.